# How to Populate Facebook Audience native ads within RecyclerView

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I want to implement native ads from Facebook Audience within a recyclerView. The ads should be positioned at a particular positions in the recyclerview, let say start at position 2, then for every 5th position with the recyclerviw. I have I have an Adapterclass that implement Recyclerview and a fragment that is responsible for the showing the items to the user.

AdapterClass

```
public class AdapterBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterBoxOffice.ViewHolderBoxOffice> {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Movie> mlistMovies = new ArrayList<>();
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
private  int previousPosition=0;
private LinearLayout  nativeAdContainer;
private LinearLayout adView;
private AdChoicesView adChoicesView;
private NativeAd nativeAd;
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
private ArrayList<Movie> filteredProductResults = new ArrayList<Movie>();


public  AdapterBoxOffice(Context context) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
    imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();
}

public void setMovieList(ArrayList<Movie> listMovies) {
    this.mlistMovies = listMovies;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setFilteredMovies(ArrayList<Movie> filteredProductResults){
    this.mlistMovies=filteredProductResults;
}
@Override
public ViewHolderBoxOffice onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=null;
   if(viewType==10){
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_ads_facebook, nativeAdContainer,  false);
       nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);
    } else {
         view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_movie_box_office, parent, false);

    }
    ViewHolderBoxOffice viewHolder = new ViewHolderBoxOffice(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {

    if (position==10){
        // Setting the Text.
        ImageView nativeAdIcon = null;

        holder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
        holder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
        holder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
        holder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());
       /* nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
        nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
        nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle())
        nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());*/

        // Downloading and setting the ad icon.
        NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
        NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, nativeAdIcon);

        // Download and setting the cover image.
        NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();
        holder.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
        /*nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);*/

        // Add adChoices icon
        if (adChoicesView == null) {
            adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(layoutInflater.getContext(), nativeAd, true);
            adView.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
        }

        nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(adView);
    }else {
        Movie currentMovie = mlistMovies.get(position);
        holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());
        Date movieReleaseDate = currentMovie.getReleaseDateTheater();
        if (movieReleaseDate != null) {
            String formmattedDate = dateFormat.format(movieReleaseDate);
            holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(formmattedDate);
        } else {
            holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(Constants.NA);

        }
        int audienceScore=currentMovie.getAudienceScore();
        if (audienceScore==-1){
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(0.0F);
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(0.5F);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(currentMovie.getAudienceScore() / 20.0F);
            holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(1.0F);
        }
        String urlThumbnail = currentMovie.getUrlThumbnail();
        loadImages(urlThumbnail, holder);
    }


    if(position>previousPosition)
    {
        comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

    }else {
        comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

    }
    previousPosition=position;


}

private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder) {
    if (urlThumbnail != null) {
        imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mlistMovies.size();
}

 class ViewHolderBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView movieThumbnail;
    private TextView movieTitle;
    private TextView movieReleaseDate;
    private RatingBar movieAudienceScore;
     private ImageView nativeAdIcon;
     private  TextView nativeAdTitle;
     private  TextView nativeAdBody;
     private MediaView nativeAdMedia;
     private TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
     private Button nativeAdCallToAction;

    public ViewHolderBoxOffice(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        movieThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieThumbnail);
        movieTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        movieReleaseDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);
        movieAudienceScore = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAudienceScore);

        // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
         nativeAdIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
         nativeAdTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
         nativeAdBody = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
         nativeAdMedia = (MediaView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
        nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
       nativeAdCallToAction = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);

    }
```

FragmentClass

```
   public class FragmentBoxOffice extends Fragment implements SortListener, BoxOfficeLoadedListener, AdListener, NativeAdsManager.Listener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private static final String STATE_MOVIES ="state_movies" ;
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private ArrayList<Movie> mlistMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private RecyclerView listMovieHits;
    private AdapterBoxOffice adapterBoxOffice;
    private TextView textVolleyError;
    private MovieSorter movieSorter;
    private NativeAd nativeAd;
    private LinearLayout  nativeAdContainer;
    private LinearLayout  adView;
    private AdChoicesView adChoicesView;
    private NativeAdsManager manager;
    /*private SwipeRefreshLayout mswipeRefreshLayout;*/

    public FragmentBoxOffice() {
        movieSorter=new MovieSorter();
    }


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBoxOffice.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentBoxOffice newInstance(String param1, String param2) {


        FragmentBoxOffice fragment = new FragmentBoxOffice();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public void onMoviesLoaded(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box_office, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        textVolleyError = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textVolleyError);
   /*    mswipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.swipeMoviesHits);

        mswipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
*/
        nativeAd=new NativeAd(getActivity(),"753251851443530_753848588050523");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(this);
        AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");

        nativeAd.loadAd();
        manager=new NativeAdsManager(getActivity(),"753251851443530_753848588050523", 5);
        manager.setListener(this);
        manager.loadAds();
        listMovieHits = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listMovieHits);
        listMovieHits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapterBoxOffice = new AdapterBoxOffice(getActivity());
        listMovieHits.setAdapter(adapterBoxOffice);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            mlistMovies=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_MOVIES);

        }else {
            mlistMovies=MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().readMovies(MovieDatabase.BOX_OFFICE);
            if (mlistMovies.isEmpty()){
                L.t(getActivity(),"executing task from the fragment");
                new TaskLoadMoviesBoxOffice(this).execute();
            }else{


            }
        }
        adapterBoxOffice.setMovieList(mlistMovies);
        adapterBoxOffice.SetOnclickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                container.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(container.getContext(), Details_Activity.class));

            }
        });
        return layout;
    }



    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoaded() {
        System.out.println("Loaded in fragment");
        nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();
        nativeAd.setAdListener(this);

        adapterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAdError(AdError adError) {

    }
```

Whenever I run the app this is what I get from my LogCat.

```
01-28 17:38:27.508 14778-14778/comeagain.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: comeagain.materialdesign, PID: 14778
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.onBindViewHolder(AdapterBoxOffice.java:99)
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.onBindViewHolder(AdapterBoxOffice.java:47)
```

I have struggled with this for while now, Kindly help..